# Color ramps with normals, 2.8 Eevee Style

Tags: node-editor, normals, eevee-render-engine

See screenshot of my implementation

[image]

In the previous blender versions, I would often create a backlight effect by using a color ramp and normals modifier in the default material settings.

The idea is to create a backlit effect or in some cases a color-based-on-angle effect that you see in some car paints.

I believe it is judged relative to the camera, so I have been unable to reproduce this effect in Evee.

How is this implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution through random experimenting: 
[image: One Solution]
A freznel input feeding into a color ramp. I used constant for my own toon applications, but I suppose this would also work for a smooth effect.

Answer (score 1):

Layer weight in place of fresnel also works pretty well. Just connect facing to Fac in the color ramp. I think it comes pretty close to the desired effect.